# Trying to find averages from a .txt but I keep getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I'm using the txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-VrWf7aqiqvnshVQ964zYsqaqRkcUoL1/view?usp=sharin

I'm running the script:

```
data = f.read()

ny_sum=0
ny_count=0
sf_sum=0
sf_count=0

for line in data.split('\n'):
    print(line)
    parts = line.split('\t')
    city = parts[2]
    amount = float(parts[4])

if city == 'San Francisco':
    sf_sum = sf_sum + amount

elif city == 'New York':
    ny_sum = ny_sum + amount
    ny_count = ny_count + 1

ny_avg = ny_sum / ny_count
sf_avg = sf_sum / sf_count

#print(ny_avg, sf_avg)

f = open('result_file.txt', 'w')
f.write('The average transaction amount based on {} transactions in New York is {}\n'.format(ny_count, ny_avg))
f.write('The average transaction amount based on {} transactions in San Francisco is {}\n'.format(sf_count, sf_avg))

if ny_avg>sf_avg:
    f.write('New York has higher average transaction amount than San Francisco\n')
else:
    f.write('San Francisco has higher average transaction amount than New York\n')
f.close()
```

And I ALWAYS get the error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

I'm pretty new-ish to Python and I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to get averages for New York and San Francisco, then export the results AND the comparison to a txt results file

Comment: The only place you're converting to a float is here:

Comment: `amount = float(parts[4])`

Comment: So apparently it's getting a value that can't be converted to a float, perhaps the empty string or something with letters

Comment: The last line in the file doesn't have enough tokens. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict as DD

with open('New Purchases.txt') as pfile:
    sums = DD(lambda: [0.0, 0])
    for line in [line.split('\t') for line in pfile]:
        try:
            k = line[2]
            sums[k][0] += float(line[4])
            sums[k][1] += 1
        except Exception:
            pass
    for k in ['San Francisco', 'New York']:
        v = sums.get(k, [0.0, 1])
        print(f'Average for {k} = ${v[0]/v[1]:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-arranged the code. I agree with BrutusFocus that the splits are making it difficult to read exactly the location on each row. I have set it so if it sees the location at any point in the row, it counts it.

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

ny_sum=0
ny_count=0
sf_sum=0
sf_count=0

for line in data.split('\n'):
    parts = line.split('\t')
    city = parts[2]
    amount = float(parts[4])
    print(city, amount)
    if "New York" in line:
        ny_sum = ny_sum + amount
        ny_count = ny_count + 1
    elif "San Francisco" in line:
        sf_sum = sf_sum + amount
        sf_count = sf_count + 1
    



ny_avg = ny_sum / ny_count
sf_avg = sf_sum / sf_count

#print(ny_avg, sf_avg)

f = open('result_file.txt', 'w')
f.write('The average transaction amount based on {} transactions in New York is 
{}\n'.format(ny_count, ny_avg))
f.write('The average transaction amount based on {} transactions in San 
Francisco is {}\n'.format(sf_count, sf_avg))

if ny_avg>sf_avg:
    f.write('New York has higher average transaction amount than San Francisco\n')
else:
    f.write('San Francisco has higher average transaction amount than New York\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still confused
Even with your re-arranged script, I STILL get the exact same error. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with the float string